# Insert a line break after bullet points using jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I have a page that a user enters comments in an HTML textarea.  Recently, users have been including bullet points in their comments.

Here is how the users have been entering comments within the HTML textarea with the bullet points:

[image]

Now, upon saving the comments, here is exactly how the comments look in the database:

[image]

I included additional columns within the database in order to be clear that there are multiple entries that have comments with bullet points.

Upon returning the data, and then displaying the comments into a JQuery datatable cell, the comments are displayed exactly as you see in the picture below:

[image]

If you'll take notice to the picture, the bullet points are in paragraph form, not separated as they initially were when first entered in the HTML textarea.

What I need to do is add a line break after each bullet point that appears in the datatable cell, so that it looks like how it was originally entered.

I am not sure if I needed to do this with MySQL, however here is how the PHP/MySQL looks when querying the database:

```
<?php
include("../include/database.php"); 

$select = "SELECT pk, region, loctype, city, twenty, twenty_comm FROM eqpstatus";   
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select);

$out = array(); 
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $out[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($out);
?>
```

I wasn't sure if there was a way to check for bullet points in a MySQL query.

On the jQuery side, here is how the datatable is returned to the page (shortened as much as possible):

```
var newData = 'process/eqpGuide.php'; 

$('#example1').DataTable({      
"ajax": {
    "url": newData,
    "type": "POST",
    "dataSrc": ''
},
"columns": [
  {"data": "region"},
  {"data": "loctype"},
  {"data": "city"},
  {"data": "twenty"},
  {"data": "twenty_comm"} // here is where I need to check for bullet points
],
"iDisplayLength": 25,
"order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
"paging": false,
"scrollY": 550,
"scrollX": true,
"bDestroy": true,
"stateSave": true,
"autoWidth": true 
});
```

So to reiterate everything I have mentioned, all I need to do pertains to the twenty_comm section of the database, and that is to add a line break after each bullet point.  I am not sure if that should or can be done in the PHP/MySQL portion of code, or if it can be done on the JQuery side within the datatable.

To put it in question form: How do I add a line break after a bullet point in either PHP/MySQL or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean you want to add a line break *before* the bullets and some whitespace after? Impossible to know what *after* is, except just before the next bullet. You could use a column `render` callback :

```
{ data: 'twenty_comm' ,
  render: function(data) {
     return data
       .replace(/•/g,'•&nbsp;&nbsp;')
       .replace(/(?!^)(•)/g, '<br>\$1')
  }
}
```

The first regex just replaces the bullet (or middot) with a bullet and two whitepaces. The next is a negative lookahead inserting `<br>` before the bullets except for the first occurence.

See **http://jsfiddle.net/cj6nk8yz/**

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much, kind sir.  In regards to my previous post, I wasn't sure why I was receiving downvotes.  I asked for a reason, but got no reply. I thought my question was clear, but apparently not. I was not going to ask another question, but I was stuck, so I provided the question above. I do believe there is an evil entity hell bent on downvoting all questions without rhyme or reason. Thank you again.  I believe you have helped me several times.  I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @JohnBeasley, thank you for accepting the answer! Yes, I think it is a real problem on SO. It is free to downvote a question, and people seem to love to downvote. I have seen it a thousand times.  It is small people who not understand a question, and then they downvote and perhaps feel like masters of the universe. Your question was perfectable understandable both the first time and the second time.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe could try to use `preg_split()` with your `twenty_comm` column and add a `<br />` char, don't know how it will render though:

```
$row['twenty_comm'] = addNewLine($row['twenty_comm']); 

function addNewLine($string){
   $newString = '';
   $split= preg_split("/[;,]+/",$string);
   foreach($split as $char){
        $newString.=$char.'<br />'; 
   }
      return $newString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***EDITED***

I think the best thing to do would be to add the new line when the user submits the text... Before the save to DB. But that's an opinion.

The second best thing would be to perform the string manipulation on server side, because relying on client's device *(the least best solution which I deleted...)* to do thing doable on the server is considered bad practice.

Try this:

```
<?php
include("../include/database.php"); 

$select = "SELECT pk, region, loctype, city, twenty, twenty_comm FROM eqpstatus";   
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select);

$out = array(); 
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $row['twenty_comm'] = implode("<br>•",explode("•",$row['twenty_comm']));
    if(substr($row['twenty_comm'],0,4)=="<br>"){
        $row['twenty_comm'] = substr($row['twenty_comm'],4);
    }

    $out[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($out);
?>
```